# Populate UITableView: empty table. Why?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiwebview

I will briefly explain.

I have two classes that pass data between them. In a class (I call it class 1) I have an Alert Controller where I get a title and an html text.

```
- (IBAction)downloadPage:(id)sender {
    NSString *html = [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
                  @"document.body.innerHTML"];

    UIAlertController * alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle: @"Inserisci il titolo"
                                                                          message: @""
                                                                   preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    [alertController addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField) {
        textField.placeholder = @"Titolo";
        textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
        textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    }];


    [alertController addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
        // Do you calculation and UI refresh on the main thread
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSArray * textfields = alertController.textFields;

            UITextField * title = textfields[0];
            InfoHtml *newFeed = [[InfoHtml alloc] init];
            newFeed.title = title.text;
            newFeed.html = html;

            [self.arrayHTML addObject:newFeed];

            NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self.arrayHTML]; 
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:data forKey:@"html"]; //salvo in userdefault
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
        });
    }]];
```

Where, InfoHtml is a class model of this type:

```
@interface InfoHtml : NSObject <NSCoding>
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *html;
@end
```

Ok. Now:

The second class (which I call class 2) needs to check if there are any data saved from class 1 and if there is to print it all in an UITableView

Then:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
     self.arrayHTML = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; 
}

-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    NSData *data = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"html"];

    if(data!=nil){         
        self.arrayHTML = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData: data];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }else{
        NSLog(@"no data");
    }
```

I have inserted the data extraction within the **viewWillAppear** method because this controller is connected to a controller tab bar, so each time I open this controller, you have to check if there are any new data or not.

Then, in cellForRowAtIndexPath, i have:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    InfoHtml *infoToShow = [self.arrayHTML objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = infoToShow.title; //setto titolo
    return cell;
}
```

I do not understand why UITableView remains empty and does not populate. Data is present because `NSData * data = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey: @ "html"];` It gives me something other than nil.

Comment: Did you set the delegate and dataSource of the table view ?

Comment: @AbdAl-rhmanTaherBadary yep

Comment: Did you override `numberOfRowsInSection` to return your array count ?

Comment: @GIJOW yep, `(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.arrayHTML.count;
}`

Comment: Next I would debug with a breakpoint in this line to see if delegate is working and if your array is returning some value other than zero

Comment: @GIJOW I printed `NSLog (@ "%", self.arrayHTML.count);` In numberForRowInSection and is 0.

Comment: bingo... thats why your tableview isn't populated

Comment: @GIJOW But it isnt possible! I have `NSData * data = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey: @ "html"];`
     `if(data! = Nil) {NSLog (@ "data found");` and the application always prints **data found** every time i open this controller :O

Comment: You can have data in your object (the object itself is already not nil) but you have nothing in your array. Your object is one thing, the array another completely different

Comment: this line is messing up `self.arrayHTML = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData: data];`

Comment: @GIJOW why....?

Comment: because is the moment where you populate your array. If your array is zero and your object is not nil... gives me just this line. Try logging your entire array right after this line to see what's inside

Comment: @GIJOW i printed `NSLog(@"%@", self.arrayHTML.count);` **soon after** `self.arrayHTML = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData: data];`. Result 0.

Comment: time to do your work and dig your problem...

Comment: I dont understand how to fix 